# Python Mongoengine/MongoDB filter query by string length

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoengine

How do I filter a field in a document by string length? I'm using MongoEngine as an ORM.

I know the below is incorrect but I'm trying to do something like this:

```
from mongoengine import Q
people_with_no_phone = People.objects(Q(phoneNumber=None) | Q(phoneNumber__len__lt=9)).count()
```

I know Mongo has a `strLenCP` but unsure how to use it in this context.

Comment: What is your condition for filter?
Do you want to check whether that particular field is empty or not?
Do you want to check whether that field is less than or greater than some length?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      {
        "$strLenCP": "$<YOUR_FIELD_NAME>"
      },
      12
    ]
  }
})
```

Here, I have used **$eq** operator to just check whether any document out of the many documents present in the collection have a field whose length is equal to 12. You can use **$gt, $lt, $gte, $lte**, however you want your end result to be.